# AS3 - Massive Numbers/Integers, Beyond MAX_VALUE

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone help me write a class, e.g. BigNumber.as (or BigInt.as) which will:

- Allow for really really big numbers/integers.
- Include a method to express a number in format "1.54 Million", "1.98 Vigintillion" and so on...
- Allow the maximum number to stop only at the last number word (e.g. Million, Vigintillion, etc) in the defined list. (e.g. list built from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers under Standard dictionary numbers [Short scale])

I had an idea to have a class which contains 2 Number values ("value" and "timesMaxedOut"). When "value" >= Number.MAX_VALUE, it would then increment "timesMaxedOut" by 1 and reset "value" back to the difference that the value went over by.

The problem? It seems if you hit or surpass "MAX_VALUE" then the Number will reset to 0. I'm also sure it would then be difficult to properly multiply or divide numbers with this approach, as it would need to take into account "timesMaxedOut" just for the calculations to work correctly.

My goal is to write a game which would allow players to reach really big numbers, and play indefinitely essentially, but AS3 lacks very large number support it seems.

Comment: as3-crypto has an implementation for BigInteger [see here](https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto/blob/master/src/com/hurlant/math/BigInteger.as). Maybe that will help you out. Also, your problem can be solved by defining a `MAX_VALUE` yourself which is lower than the actual `MAX_VALUE`, couldn't it?

Comment: Thank you. I will try setting my own max value and see what happens!

Comment: If by setting you mean `Number.MAX_VALUE = 10`, that won't work. Define another constant in your BigNumber class.